# Calling a function from the same header file from two C++ files in the same project

Tags: c++, include

I have a program consisting of 3 files:

main.c; other.c and event.h

event.h has a function called 'event()'.

I'd like to call the event() function from both main.c and other.c. At the top of both main.c and other.c I include the line

```
#include "event.h"
```

...and within each of the .c files I have the lines

```
event();
```

However I receive the following compile errors (Visual C++)

"fatal error LNK1169: one or more multiply defined symbols found"

"error LNK2005: _event@16 already defined in main.obj"

...What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The definition of the function ie its code can only be given in one place.

The header should include just the declaration of the event function and the code implementing the function needs to be in a .c file.

e.g.

in event.h

```
void event();
```

and in any ONE .c file - could be either of main.c or other.c or probably better a separate file event.c

```
void event()
{
    printf( "Hello\n" );
}
```

Comment: Thank you - this is the solution I required

Comment: "The header should include just the [ **declaration** ] of the event function...". *Declaration* and *definition* are not interchangeable terms in C++. You could also have used the term *prototype*.

Comment: @Emile - yes I know - a typo - I got the correct one in the first line and spent time double checking but missed:)

Comment: Yeah, you gotta type quickly here if you want to get an answer in before the others. :-)

Answer (score 2):

You have two choices: either don't define the function in the header, or define it as inline.  The first is covered in other answers, and the latter is as easy as prepending "inline" to the function definition:

```
inline
void example() {
  do_stuff();
}
```

Whether you want to define the function inline or not is, today, all about your convenience and *not about optimization.*  Which is easier for you?  Inline functions are almost always easier to begin with (i.e. prototyping and first versions); you can always reverse that decision, if needed, later.

Answer (score 1):

You should not define `event()` in `event.h`. Because `event.h` is included both in `main.c` and `other.c,` it ends up being defined twice.

You need to declare it in event.h, with the function signature, such as:

`void event();`

And put the definition in an `event.c` file where you will put the function body. The function will be defined only in this `event.c` file, and the two other `.c` files will only include the declaration.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you have defined `event()` in `event.h`, like this:

```
void event()
{
 ....
}
```

But in header you have to *declare* function and then *define* it in .cpp So you have to do the following:
**event.h**

```
// declaration
void event();
```

**event.cpp**

```
#include "event.h"
// implementation
void event()
{
 ....
}
```